# Speed up groupby and aggregate in large datasets

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any chance to speed up the use of groupby and agrregate on large datasets?

I have dataframe like this:

```
User Category
A    Cat 
B    Dog    
C    Cat
A    Dog
```

I want to display all categories to each user in array, like this:

```
User Category
A    [Cat,Dog]
B    [Dog]
C    [Cat]
```

The code I'm using for this looks like this:

```
 df = df.groupby('User')['Category'].aggregate(
        lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).reset_index()
```

But the processing time for large files is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us `drop_duplicate` before `groupby`

```
out = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('User')['Category'].agg(list)
Out[249]: 
User
A    [Cat, Dog]
B         [Dog]
C         [Cat]
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Comment: But in that way "Categories" are duplicated in list eg. ```[Cat, Cat, Dog]``` I want only ```[Cat,Dog}```

Comment: @Rafal did you check `drop_duplicates()` ?